# C: program stops with no error

Tags: c, apache, sockets

I'm new with C and especially with sockets. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


int time_me = 0;
 int yes = 1;
 char buffer[1024];
 int newsockfd, recv_length, sockfd;
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
 ssize_t number;
 if (sockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");
 bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));



 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(80);



//write(sockfd,"From Server",11);


 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

 connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
 send(sockfd, "GET /1/ HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET /1/ HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"), 0);




 while(yes)
 {

     sleep(1);
     if(send(sockfd, "as\r\n\r\n", strlen("as\r\n\r\n"), 0) > 0)
     {
        printf("Alive on %d Second\n", time_me);

     }
     else
     {

        printf("Dead on %d Second\n", time_me);
     }
     time_me++;

 printf("I'm Done\n");
 }









}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to make a correct HTTP GET request and after that make some bad request and see for how long does socket stay alive.I know that I can check socket timeout in apache.conf file and it says 300 seconds. But my problem is that after 31 seconds program just stops working. It doesn't even go in else statement nor says **I'm Done** I can't figure out why. Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: If with "*stops working*" are not referring to "it ends", then mostly likely the call to `send()` blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is not reading all the data that you're sending and that makes the socket buffer get filled up, causing the `send(2)` call to block.

After 31 `send(2)` calls your buffer gets filled up with data and the socket, which is open in blocking mode, cannot handle more bytes. You should set the socket to non blocking mode or use `select(2)`, `poll(2)` or something like that to do what you want. Please look into `setsockopt(2)` manual (`O_NONBLOCK` flag).

If you use `select(2)` or use the non blocking socket you should wait when `send(2)` returns `-1` and `errno` is `EAGAIN` (or `EWOULDBLOCK`), because that's where your program is freezing. You should study the socket manuals very well (`socket(2)` and `setsockopt(2)` at least) to understand how to achieve your desired goals.

AND, as Blake noted below, you should also check every function call return value to check if there are errors. After getting an error on `send(2)` or any libc related calls you should check the error using the `errno` variable, `perror(3)` or `strerror(3)` functions.

Anyway, if you want to know when a connection/socket has been dropped, use `select(2)` to check the read status of the socket. That will do what you want.

Comment: For a non-blocking socket the buffer wouldn't fill up slower.

Comment: Yes, but he doesn't want to fill up slower, he just want to know why it is freezing without an error and a non blocking socket would come in hand for him.

Comment: Then why not explicitly mention, that `send()` blocks?

Comment: So you're saying that socket buffer on server side is filled up and it disconnects me?

Comment: And even when using a non-blocking socket, `send()` might as well return `-1` although the connection still would be valid.

Comment: @Ojs no, you don't get disconnected, you just can't send more data than the server is reading (which is none) and the socket buffer.

Comment: If i cahnge sleep(1) to sleep(10) and make string that is sent smaller would that make my program work for more than 31 seconds?

Comment: Yes, but the effect would be the same and nothing would effectively change. The server is not receiving your data after a defined point (maybe after sending a newline) and there is no point in sending data. After sending the first few lines (maybe two) you should just use select(2) to wait for the socket to be closed to get the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

It will help you debug your code if you try to catch each possible error.

Put something like this under each system function. Most of them return -1 on error, and 0 or more on success.

```
if (returned < 0) {
    printf("called_function(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}
```

For ease of use, just change the name of called_function() in the printf to whatever function you're catching errors from, and returned to whatever your variable is called.

Comment: Why test the socket's value (besides when calling `socket()`)? You want to test the system calls result!

Comment: sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
So wouldn't sockfd be the result from the system call?

Comment: I added "*besides when calling socket()*" to my comment, 1min later.

Comment: My 1st comment referred to this wording: "*each socket-**related** function.*"

Comment: Anyways this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Ah, I get you now. I should reword, I only used the socket as an example for this case.I know it doesn't answer his question but he's new to C (Probably not far behind me!) and I find it very helpful to use this very often to see very quickly what has caused an issue.

Comment: "*very often*"? I'd say you should do "always"! :-)